# Using a geodjango PointField with geography=True, my distance calculations are wrong

Tags: python, postgis, distance, geodjango

Here's my model:

```
class ExchangeArea(models.Model):
    """
    An Exchange Service Area, calculated from a phone exchange and surrounding census tracts. 
    """
    coordinates = models.PointField(null=True, geography=True)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(null=True, geography=True) 
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    adopts = AdoptionManager()

    def __unicode__(self):        
        return '(%f, %f)' % (self.coordinates.coords[1], self.coordinates.coords[0])
```

And here's my `ipython` terminal output:

```
for e in ExchangeArea.objects.distance(ea.coordinates)[:10]: print e.distance, e.coordinates.wkt

0.0 m POINT (-121.4749999999999801 36.5399999999999991)                  
34.3149213171 m POINT (-87.4350000000000023 32.2049999999999983)  
34.1483824654 m POINT (-87.6800000000000068 31.6400000000000006)          
1.30461680198 m POINT (-122.4000000000000057 37.4600000000000009)         
27.2054594705 m POINT (-94.2750000000000057 35.9950000000000045)          
34.2874590776 m POINT (-87.7500000000000000 30.3550000000000004)         
29.441773469 m POINT (-92.1550000000000011 33.8650000000000020)          
5.51086451056 m POINT (-116.1352147188304826 35.1775313564249501)        
2.11899150541 m POINT (-119.6700000000000017 37.6499999999999986)        
27.6825400749 m POINT (-93.7950000000000017 36.1649999999999991)
```

Using [this code](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html) as a reference, the first non-zero distance should be:

```
3151063.676 m
```

### Update

So using `south` I've worked around this issue, ideally retaining the same level of accuracy (with reduced speed) by switching back to a normal geometry field (removing `geography=true` from my model) and using `spheroid=True` on my distance queries. They are now in a more sensible order of magnitude and still treat the earth as an spheroid (which is why I was using `geography=True` in the first place). Still would like to know what the deal with geography fields is. Leaving this open until someone can explain.

Comment: OpenGeo have a useful writeup on the difference between geography and geometry calculations in PostGIS 1.5: http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used geodjango but I'm wondering if the geography=true is just a notice to it to tell it the data is stored in geography format.  Are your geometries in postgis stored as geography or geometry?

Comment: It does save it in geography format. That was the idea. My understanding was that would automatically ensure all distance calculations would treat the earth as a spheroid. However I never got that to work (as I detailed in the Update). It appears it gives me the angular distances rather than a distance in meters.

Comment: So: at the moment the solution is to store it as geometry rather than geography, and `geodjango` can do the spheroid calculation for me, which I assume just calls the corresponding `postgis` function.